# How much traffic a Magento 2.2 can handle on VPS with 2 GB RAM with! CPU core?

Tags: magento2.2, server-setup

To run properly for few users or development and testing shared hosting is enough for Magento 2.2.

But if go further and run Magento 2.2 on VPS. 
How much traffic magento 2.2 can handle on VPS with 2GB RAM and 1 Core CPU  (Basically Godaddy - Launch plan VPS)?

Or should we need to go higher version of VPS or Dedicated Server (I know dedicated server is not required in starting.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com or here.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) complete MySQLTuner report 
E) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis to improve speed.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to give a prescription that would apply so generally, simply because of the extreme variation between Magento 2 installations.

Assuming you have full optimizations, I still wouldn't want anything less than 2 cores and 4 GiB, offhand I'd say your specs are too low though. You should be able to get away with the larger VPS, assuming you're careful about your settings.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Recently Magento has launched 2.2.7 and 2.3 and they are very slow on even my local system with 8 GB Ram and i5 6th generation Intel processor.

Comment: Magento is becoming very complex and ram consuming software day by day. It should have rest of modules should be in options. Only basic module should be enable. And db is also very big and complex but thank to orm we can manage by model very easily, still load the MySQL.

Comment: Full optimizations definitely means disabling as many modules as possible, they are completely out of control.  I have no idea why they had to include so many in one bloated monstrosity, instead of breaking them out to be managed individually.   It defeats the entire point of being modular.

Answer (score 0):

I tested time ago with 2 GB RAM and was very slow, I don't recommend this.

For almost the same amount of money, you can get a VPS - 1600 GB SSD with 60GB RAM.

Give a try with hosting provider Contabo. Maybe don't forget review feedback first about this hosting provider and take your decision.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider your suggestion. Actually I am used to GoDaddy. I should check other providers as well in market.

Comment: @RavinderSinghRawat Is your GoDaddy account using SSD or rotatiing media?